# How to make it affect device font size to RichText and TextSpan

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a problem with `RichText` and `TextSpan` widgets. All `Text` widgets are affected by device font size (changed in settings) but `RichText` not. Any ideas about to solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have solved it this way:

```
RichText(
    textScaleFactor: MediaQuery.of(context).textScaleFactor, <--- add this
    text: ...
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually `RichText` is one of the lower level widgets that you need to handle many things yourself.

You should try to use `Text.rich()` instead. It's pretty much the same thing as `RichText` but inherits styles from the parent widget tree.